# Saving the pre-sanitized filename of an attachment as the Title or Caption

Tags: images, uploads, hooks

I've tried a fair bit of searching but nothing has come up trumps so far. I have a client that has to upload a lot of images to galleries and to save time he saves the captions as the filenames when in Photoshop. Personally I would prefer to do it within WP but this is the workflow he has and won't budge!

Is there any way of grabbing the pre-sanitized filename and saving it as meta data?

I've looked at `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` but this doesn't hook at the right point from what I can see.

Comment: Title is not metadata of attachment, so I am a bit confused. you're trying to save some metadata (with key/value) or title and caption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` hook does not recognize an attachment ID yet. It's too early and runs the pre-sanitized file name (before moving the attachment and storing it as a post)

#### The Logic

What you can do is use that hook `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` but instead, store a transient with a short life that contains the pre-sanitized file name.

Once the attachment is added, we can check that with `add_attachment()` hook. You can update the attachment title, caption, or any other metadata you want by using the stored transient value.

Finally you will remove the transient.

I did test this method and seems to work on multi and single attachment uploads on my localhost installation.

Ok this is how you can do it with code.

#### Hook in wp_handle_upload_prefilter and store the pre-sanitized file name (without extension) as a WordPress transient using `set_transient`

```
add_action( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', '_remember_presanitized_filename' );
function _remember_presanitized_filename( $file ) {
    $file_parts = pathinfo( $file['name'] );
    set_transient( '_set_attachment_title', $file_parts['filename'], 30 );
    return $file;
}
```

#### Capture the transient option to update the added attachment

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', '_set_attachment_title' );
function _set_attachment_title( $attachment_id ) {
    $title = get_transient( '_set_attachment_title' );
    if ( $title ) {

        // to update attachment title and caption
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $attachment_id, 'post_title' => $title, 'post_excerpt' => $title ) );

        // to update other metadata
        update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $title );

        // delete the transient for this upload
        delete_transient( '_set_attachment_title' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, 

For some reason I wasn't notified about your reply! I can't thank you enough, this is absolutely perfect. Just tried it locally and is working fine! I've never used transients before, but feel like you've just opened a door to more learning! Sincere thanks!